# Understanding spacy textcat_multilabel scorer output

Tags: spacy, text-classification

I'm trying to understand the output of my textcat_multilabel job. I have 4 text categories and I'm using spacy version 3.2.0 (The methodologies have changed a lot recently and I don't really understand the documentation).

| E | # | LOSS TEXTC... | CATS_SCORE | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1.00 | 51.86 | 0.52 |
| 0 | 200 | 122.15 | 52.90 | 0.53 |

This is what I have in my config file. (btw. What is v1?)

```
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.textcat_multilabel_scorer.v1"}
threshold = 0.5
```

In fact, everything in the standard config file is unchanged from the suggestions except the dropout which I increased to 0.5.
The final row of my job shows these values:  0    8400           2.59       87.29    0.87

I am very impressed with the results that I'm getting with this job. Just need to understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

- E is epochs
- `#` is training iterations / batches ([see here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:%7E:text=what%20are%20iterations%2C%20steps%2C%20epochs....%3F))
- LOSS_TEXTCAT is the loss of your textcat component. Loss normally fluctuates the first few iterations and then trends downward. The exact values are meaningless.
- SCORE_TEXTCAT is the score of your textcat component on your dev set, see the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/scorer#score_cats) for some details on that.
- SCORE is overall score of your pipeline, a weighted average of any components you have. But you only have a textcat so it's basically the same as that score.

v1 is just version 1, components are versioned in case they are updated later  so you can use older versions with newer code.